# `require': cannot load such file -- cancan (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, cancan

I'm using the CanCan gem with ActiveAdmin. It is working as expected in dev, but when pushed to a staging server I get the following error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- cancan (LoadError)
```

In my case, this is caused by [the 'require' line](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/868ee6f3de68f177415e4d83e0fd0d04843b0653/lib/active_admin/cancan_adapter.rb#L1) in ActiveAdmin's CanCan adapter.

I've searched Google for potential explanations but have come up empty-handed.

What might be the cause of such an error, and how can I go about fixing it?

**Update:**

Here is my `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_user!
  config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
  config.cancan_ability_class = "Ability"
  config.current_user_method = :current_user
  config.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path
  config.allow_comments = false
  config.batch_actions = true
end
```

Comment: post your gemfile. what happens if you run "$> require 'cancan'" from the rails console in the staging environment?

Comment: The result of running `require 'cancan'` from the Rails console is `=> false`. The relevant lines in the Gemfile are `gem 'cancan'` and `gem 'activeadmin', '0.6.0', github: "gregbell/active_admin"`

Comment: post your activeadmin initializer file

Comment: did you run `bundle install` in your staging env?

Comment: @Vimsha Yes, via Capistrano. The success of `require 'cancan'` mentioned above also suggests that the bundle installed correctly. @Nicolas Posted.

Comment: does your boot.rb requires rubygems?. try requiring cancan through the gemfile. gem 'cancan', require: 'cancan'.

Comment: Yes, boot.rb requires rubygems. Tried `gem 'cancan', require: 'cancan'` but got the same result.

Comment: Found the solution; see below.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the entire machine fixed this.

I had tried restarting both nginx and unicorn, but I had yet to restart the machine itself. For whatever reason, this did the trick.

Thanks for your thoughts / suggestions.